# How to join time/int intervals by delta?

Tags: python, list

I have a simple list of intervals:

```
[ 
  { "begin" : 10, "end" : 20 },
  { "begin" : 1, "end" : 2 },
  { "begin" : 5, "end" : 7 },
  { "begin" : 100, "end" : 200 } 
]
```

How to join intervals by condition

```
if abs(current["end"] - next["begin"] < 40) ?
```

result must be:

```
[ 
  { "begin" : 1, "end" : 20 },
  { "begin" : 100, "end" : 200 } 
]
```

My solution:

```
from pyinter import interval, IntervalSet
def test():
    g = sorted(g, key=itemgetter("begin"))
    ln = len(g)
    if ln < 2: return
    i = 0
    while i < ln - 1:
       if abs(g[i]["end"] - g[i+1]["begin"]) < 40:
           g[i]["end"] = g[i+1]["begin"]
       i = i + 1

    a = IntervalSet()
    for i in range(len(g)):
        a.add(interval.closed( g[i]["begin"], g[i]["end"] ))

    res = []
    for key in a:
        res.append({ "begin" : key.lower_value, "end" : key.upper_value })
    return res
```

but it is a very ugly

Comment: What if there's an overlap?

Comment: Question and result is unclear, confusing!

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
list_dicts = [  {"begin" : 10, "end" : 20 },
                {"begin" : 1, "end" : 2 },
                {"begin" : 5, "end" : 7 },
                {"begin" : 100, "end" : 200 }]

# sorted by d['begin']
ld = sorted(list_dicts, key=lambda d:d['begin'])

# merge
results = [ld[0]]
for idx, d in enumerate(ld[1:], 1):
    if abs(d['begin'] - results[-1]['end']) < 40:
        results[-1]['end'] = d['end']
    else:
        results.append(d)


print(results)
# Output
[{'begin': 1, 'end': 20}, {'begin': 100, 'end': 200}]
```